# Multiple jointures Errors - SQL (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I am new to coding and I am struggling with a particular use case.

I have database A which is like this :

| Date | Segment | Product | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date1 | A | B | X |
| Date1 | A | C | Y |
| Date2 | A | B | Y |
| Date2 | A | D | Y |

I have a reference table (let's call it B) that I use to retrieve the equivalent date of "Date" but for the previous year. I'll call it 'Date_PY'

It is giving me this :

| Date | Date_PY | Segment | Product | Attendance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date1 | Date2 | A | B | X |
| Date1 | Date2 | A | C | Y |
| Date2 | Date3 | A | B | Z |
| Date2 | Date3 | A | D | W |

At the end, I would like to "join" back this new temporary database (let's call it C) to the old one, to retrieve corresponding PY for each date.

| Date | Date_PY | Segment | Product | Attendance | Attendance_PY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date1 | Date2 | A | B | X | Z |
| Date1 | Date2 | A | C | Y | 0 |
| Date1 | Date2 | A | D | 0 | W |
| Date2 | Date3 | A | B | Z | ... |
| Date2 | Date3 | A | D | W | ... |

Here Z attendance is both in the third line as it is attendance for Date2, and in first line as it is PY attendance for Date1.
Please also note that all dates exist in both databases, but some segment/product can have values for Date1 but not for its PY equivalent, and reciprocally. This is the case for the product D here : in that situation I would need to generate an additional line with 0 in Attendance column. Reciprocally, if there is no value for Attendance_PY, I want to keep the row and put a 0 (example on second line).

I'm looking for help as nothing I tried is working. Joining A to B was quite easy with LEFT JOIN, but joining C back to A is not working properly

Thanks !
Enzo

I tried various solutions :

> Left join with COALESCE on selected variables is not returning me rows where I do not have values for Attendance.
> FULL OUTER JOIN is returning me NULL values for the Date_PY column and duplicate rows

Also tried various alternatives but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Click here](https://dbfiddle.uk/JHxLc9S_), I created two tables, one to hold some data for this year and one to hold some data for previous years.

I created a Union with the two tables to get all the data, then placed this in a select statement, then left joined the previous years table back to the to select statement to get the previous years date and attendance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please keep your answer completely on stackoverflow. You can add code answers, there's no need to link to a third party site.